# AWS glueでデータ部分までに複数行存在する場合のクローラ

Tags: aws

AWSのglueサービスで下記のようなCSVファイルをクロールしデータカタログを作成しすると
分類がUNKNOWNになります．

```
DATE=2018-11-01

city,score
tokyo,2
osaka,3
kyoto,4
...
```

（最初の２行を除くと正しくデータカタログが作成されます）
データカタログを正しく作成するためにクローラで対応する方法はありますか？
lambdaなどで１行目がヘッダー列になるようにするしかありませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

手元でちょっと試してみましたが、この形式のファイルをクローラーに自動で分類させるのは不可能かもしれません。

しかしながら、手動でテーブルを作成することで、AthenaやETLジョブで処理できる形が作れるようでした。
Serdeパラメータに`skip.header.line.count: 3` を追加するとうまくいきます。
テーブル作成画面では設定できないので、いったん作ってから編集することになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます．色々調べましたが無理そうだとわかりました．ご指摘の手動パラメタで対応したいと思います。